# What's the name of automatic/self moving table equipments?

Tags: home-automation

There are some self/automatic moving home decor objects that oscillate like pendulum either kept in entrance drawing room or some office table.I think that they move without any power source (battery). 
I want to buy them but not able to find out the name of these kind of products.

Comment: I haven't seen what you seem to be talking about. Do you have a name or Google image? I'd recommend a DB Fletcher Capstan instead https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bh_qn62zny0

Comment: No bro. I am not looking for expanding table. Instead i am looking for objects(toy like) kept on tables that moves automatically without any power source. I will try to add some scenes from movies/serials etc if i find them.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification it just didn't click the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [Desktop Kinetic Sculptures](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1126&bih=901&q=desktop%20kinetic%20sculpture&oq=kinetic%20desktop&gs_l=img.3.0.0i8i30.1476.11903.0.14968.15.14.0.1.1.0.203.1717.5j8j1.14.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.15.1719.hry5pQ9Gj00). You'll have to click "visit website" for the sculpture(s) you like for dimensions or to see if it's a retailer. But, I'm pretty sure they're just in specialty shops now.

Comment: Glad to help, the "toy like" really helped.